# Why the command in .bash_logout can't run after reboot?

Tags: bash

Os : debian9.
Create a log file.

```
touch $HOME/logout.log
```

Add a command in .bash_logout.

```
vim .bash_logout
echo  $(date)  >>  $HOME/logout.log
```

Now login with account name `test`,and create `/home/test/logout.log`.

I want to write date info in `/home/test/logout.log`,why no date info after reboot?
Nothing in /home/test/logout.log after reboot.

Comment: You need to be logged in to a user, then when you logout this file gets executed. Hence the name `bash_logout`. Can you specify _exactly_ when you want `echo $(date)` to be executed? Also you can just do `date >> $HOME/logout.log`

Comment: At reboot to write time info into  $HOME/logout.log.

Comment: `date  >>  $HOME/logout.log` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### first

```
echo $(date) >> $HOME/logout.log
```

can be replace by

```
date >> $HOME/logout.log
```

### next,

`.bash_logout` is run when you disconnect, not when there is a reboot.

- A **reboot** is when you restart host, effectively killing (more or less nicely) all it process, database, webserver and so on.
- A **logout** is when you (or any user) disconnect from interactive session, the host stay up, as well as database and the like.

If you want script to be executed during a schedule shutdown, place then in `/etc/init.d` , then have a link like `K01-trace-logout` in `/etc/rcX.d` where X is your run-level (result of `who -r`).

### finaly

Be aware that unexpected shutdown (power outage, disk I/O freezing) will leave no trace in log file.

Comment: I have a question, would `$HOME` in this case be `/root` or would it be the the home directory of the user who initiates the reboot, assuming the script is in `/etc/rc6.d`.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson No, unless you have way to trap which user start shutdown (by way of sudo for instance)...

Answer (score 1):

You need to run bash as login shell. You need to login as the user and when you log-out from the interactive login shell - the .bash_logout script will be executed.

Comment: Command in .bash_logout execute in login shell ,most of time i'm in non-login shell (graphic mode).